# How to implement pull refresh animation on a recyclerView without using external libraries?

Tags: android, android-animation, pull-to-refresh, swiperefreshlayout

I have a simple example where I have a RecyclerView that I want to be refreshed when the user pulls on the top of the list! I have used swipeRefresh layout. However when the list is refreshed the refresh icon is shown on on top of the items. I want to have an animation where the list goes down as the icon is shown and back up when the refresh is done! Basically I want it to look something like instagrams refresh animation. I know that this can be done using external libraries but most of the libraries that I have found have not been updated in a long time!

This is a simple example just to explain what I have done so far:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var adapter: PersonListAdapter
    private val personList = ArrayList<Person>()
    private lateinit var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        loadData()
        swipe_refresh_layout.setOnRefreshListener {
            swipe_refresh_layout.isRefreshing = false
        }
    }

    private fun loadData() {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        adapter = PersonListAdapter(personList, this)

        // RecyclerView setup
        my_recycler_view.layoutManager = layoutManager
        my_recycler_view.adapter = adapter

        // Load data
        for (i in 0..4) {
            personList.add(Person("my name", 20 + i, R.drawable.img1))
            personList.add(Person("me", 10 + i, R.drawable.img1))
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()


    }
}
```

This is my XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_fall_down"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `SwipeRefreshLayout` which it should extends main SwipeRefreshLayout and then override methods

try get help by taking a look at that open source libraries

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way will be to use external libraries, why do you need to recreate the wheel? If you want to learn something new and enhance your coding skills I would recommend fork the most popular Github repos with a swipe to refresh implementation and dive deep to implementation details with your own changes. https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=swipe+to+refresh+android&type=Repositories